# Django wrap SQL as Command

Tags: django, api

i have a question,

is it possible to wrap a SQL command on Django Command ?

because i have this SQL, that need to be executed during deploy

```
update foo
set bar = 'baz'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly